# why the The 15N–{ 1H} spectrum of [Pt(NH3)3 H2O] shows 6 lines instead of 3 if all the NH3 are supposed to be equivalent?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

The 15N spectra for [Pt(NH3)3 H2O] shows 6 lines, I don't understand why because the 3 (NH3) are chemically equivalent and when interacting with Pt will generate a double satellite lines and a middle line for a total of three, so why it is giving me 6 lines?. are they not all chemically equivalent? or is there coupling interaction of  the 15nitrogen  with oxygen?. Also there is a note that says there are no  2J(N, N) observed in this spectra.

I was asked to use the method of successive splitting to corroborate the spectrum lines obtained but as I said  don't understand why there are 6 lines....

Answer (score 3):

You may have missed the impact of ligand bonding geometry.  If, as seems likely, the complex is actually $\ce{Pt^{2+}}$ bonded to the ligands, we should expect a square planar geometry.  Thereby, one ammonia ligand is opposite the water ligand and not equivalent to the two other ammonia ligands which are adjacent instead.